# Как запретить вызов функции JS из отладчика браузера?

Tags: javascript, html, отладка

У меня есть сайт рулетка, там есть две проблемные **HTML кнопки** с вызовом `onClick="bet('betMin')"` и вторая кнопка с вызовом `onClick="bet('betMax')"` Функция содержит в себе в Ajax, который отправляет в php, соответственно, `type: type,`, *(type - это как раз `betMin` или `betMax`)* но вот беда... Если в отладчике браузера поменять, например, у кнопки, которой `onClick="bet('betMin')"` на `onClick="bet('betMax')"`, то функция вызовется два раза, с разными параметрами. Проблема в том, что приходит один `success` на два варианта. Как это пофиксить? Может в php проверку какую-нибудь сделать на запросы?

Comment: на странице можно сделать некий уникальный id (изначально полученный от сервера), который клиент передаст на сервер, а сервер проверит при получении запроса и заодно запишет факт того что его с этим id уже вызывали и тогда при втором вызове он сможет понять что вызов повторный и обработать соответствующим образом

Comment: Браузер — территория пользователя, вы не сможете ему ничего запретить. Затруднить использовать отладчик — возможно, но не запретить. Всё должно разрабатываться с учётом этого

Comment: @Mike интересно бы услышать пример

Comment: "то функция вызовется два раза, с разными параметрами" - это еще почему?

Comment: @RomanKashirov Интересно было бы до конца понять вопрос. На данный момент я смог из него понять только общую картину, что надо фактически запретить некий повторный вызов. Я например вообще никакой проблемы в замене кода на кнопках не вижу, ну вызовется не та функция, которая изначально предполагалась и что из того, просто считайте что клиент нажал другую кнопку, он же имеет право нажать другую кнопку. так же как и кликать быстро то в одну то в другую

Comment: @Mike проблема куда серьезнее из-за этого. Дело в том, что в php есть две функции генерации чисел mt_rand(), на каждую кнопку. Они отличаются. Просто это очень долго объяснять и боюсь, что мой рассказ будет не прост для понимания. Вообщем проблема в том, что функция выполняется одна, итог получается один для двух кнопок, а должен каждому своё. Я думаю это проблема с Ajax запросом.

Comment: ajax просто передает то, что его попросили передать. открывайте отладку в браузере, смотрите что реально он передает и что получает в ответ.

Comment: [Вот моя рулетка](http://vistelg.com) кнопка меньше и больше, передаёт, при нажатии, Ajax POST action.php тип кнопки 'betMin' или 'betMax'. PHP распознаёт тип и выполняет соответственный код. Если поменять в отладчике тип кнопки, например у "Меньше", то выполняется и 'betMin' и 'betMax' @Mike

Comment: ну выполняется и что из того ? это же то же самое, что пользователь нажал по очереди на обе кнопки. Он в любом случае может это быстро сделать до того как получит ответ хотя бы на одну из них

Comment: @Mike не знаю каким образом это происходит, я в PHP уже пытался пофиксить это, но говорю же... Функции у кнопок практически одинаковые, но глобальные функции из которых берутся рандомные числа, разные. Выглядит это примерно так `$user = Auth::user();
    $hash = json_decode($this->hash_generate_min());
    $user->salt1 = $hash->salt_1;
    $user->number = $hash->number;
    $user->salt2 = $hash->salt_2;
$user->hash = hash('sha512', $hash->salt_1.$hash->number.$hash->salt_2);
$user->save();` Так вот, когда происходит замена в отладке, то выполняется на две кнопки лишь hash_generate_min()